# Stack simulation not storing elements

Tags: java

```
public class Stack {
    Student Sarray[] = new Student[1000];
    int nrElem=0;

    public Student[] getAll(){
        return this.Sarray;
    }

    public void push(Student x){

        this.nrElem++;  
        this.Sarray[this.nrElem]=x;
    }
}
```

I try to implement a stack manually and I have a little problem.The first element I insert is stored and replaced when I insert another one.What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Ctrl {
    Stack x = new Stack();
public void addC(Student s){
    if(findById(s.getId()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Err!Duplicate id!/n");  
    } else {
        if(s.getGrade()>10)
            System.out.println("Err!Grade bigger than 10!/n");  
        else{ 
        x.push(s);
        }
    }
}



public Student findById(int id){
    Stack y=new Stack();
    y=x;
    Student z= new Student() ;

    for(int i=1;i<=y.getNrElem();i++){
        z=y.pop();
        if (z.getId()==id) 
            return z;
    }
    return null;    
}
```

2different modules for Stack and Ctrl.

Comment: Perhaps you are by mistake ceating a new Stack object?

Comment: there is a problem in your code, in push method, increment of nrElem must be after assignation, or `this.Sarray[this.nrElem++] = x`, but we need to see all the other methods to see where is the bug, you didnt showed findById

Comment: @RamonBoza updated with `findById()`

Comment: `y=x;` What is `x`, where does it comes from? Please, understand people here helps each others for free, try to be generous on your question and provide as much information as you can in order to get a better feedback/answer.

Comment: where is `addC` method? is it in `Stack` class?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia different packages.

Comment: have you tried the solution provided by RamonBoza in his first comment? is it the same problem still or is it a new problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `public Student findById(int id)` you do this:

```
Stack y=new Stack(); // creates new reference to new Stack ...
y=x;                 // reference is redirected to point to the class's Stack instance
```

y points now to the class member x, which you pop empty in the follwing for loop.
That means if you make changes to the datastructure using ref `y` these changes will be seen using ref `x` since you are doing the changes on the same instance.

You may implement a search in the Stack-Class that does not change the Stack's content or you may implement this on a *copy* of your Stack. Mostly this is achieved by providing either a "Copy"-Constructor or a "clone()" method in the DataStructure's class.

For example change the above lines to

```
Stack y = new Stack(x);
// y=x We do not need this any more.
```

And in Stack class add:

```
public Stack( Stack aStack ) {
    System.arraycopy(aStack.Sarray,0,this.Sarray,0,aStack.Sarray.length);
    // By the way: please start members with a small letter!

    this.nrElem = aStack.nrElem;
}
```

P.S.: And note RamonBoza's comment, +1 for him.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `addC` method for inserting a student.
It in turn calls `findById`, which contains the following line:

```
z=y.pop()
```

For the simple case there's one element in the stack you pop it out, but never push it back.
So to fix it you either need to return elements to the stack after you pop them, or have a method in class Stack which finds elements without popping them out.

btw, you haven't provided the code for `getNrElem()` method.